# Trouble with Queries and JOINS

Tags: php, mysql, join, subquery

The main page I am using is called the Project Details Page which when you select a project number on the form will query the subform for any records pertaining to that project number and display them in this page named the (TasksSubform).
This page called (TasksSubform) uses a php file called mysqli_connect.php to obtain a database connection and assigns that connection to $dbc in the mysqli_connect.php file.
This page then query’s table 1 named 'CommonTasks', and starts displaying the data row by row in a table on the page using

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
```

Currently one of the columns in the record being displayed is named “AssignedTo” which produces the unique ID number in the Employees table instead of the text value of the employees name associated with the ID number. So, I need to be able to list the records in the CommonTasks Table using Fetch then, when it tries to display the value in the “AssignedTo” column within the Common Tasks Table, it must lookup the ID in the Employees table which equals the same value in the Common Tasks Table, and replace the number value of the Assigned To Field with the text value in the Employees table.

```
COMMONTASKS
    EMPLOYEES
    * Add
    * AssignedTo
    * Attachments
    * Cost
    * CostInDays
    * Description
    * DueDate
    * EmployeeID
    * ID
    * PercentComplete
    * Priority
    * StartDate
    * SubmissionDate
    * Title * ID
* Address
* BusinessPhone
* City
* Company
* CountryRegion
* EmailAddress
* FaxNumber
* FirstName
* HomePhone
* JobTitle
* LastName
* MobilePhone
* Notes
* StateProvince
* WebPage
* ZIPPostal Code
```

This is what I have. Yet, all it is producing is a blank in the Assigned To field on the php page.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PK5aS.png)
I am a novice to php and mysql. 
This is probably something simple which I am overlooking.
Yet, I have been troubleshooting various methods for the past few days, and just cant seem to figure out what I am doing wrong.

```
    <?php
// Get a connection for the database
require_once('../mysqli_connect.php');

// Create a query for the database


$sql = "SELECT * FROM `CommonTasks`"; 
$employee = "SELECT ID, LastName, LastName FROM Employees JOIN CommonTasks ON Employees.ID=CommonTasks.AssignedTo"; 
$emp = "SELECT LastName, FirstName FROM Employees JOIN CommonTasks WHERE Employees.ID = CommonTasks.AssignedTo LIMIT 1";
$emp1 = "SELECT id as LastName, FirstName FROM Employees WHERE ID = CommonTasks.AssignedTo LIMIT 1";
// Get a response from the database by sending the connection
// and the query
$result1 = @mysqli_query($dbc, $sql);
$result2 = @mysqli_query($dbc, $emp);
 $result = $dbc->query($sql);
$link = "commntasks-insertdata.php"
?> 
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Common Tasks-subform</title>
<meta name="viewport"charset="utf-8" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

</head>
<body>
<?php

echo " <table border='1' #6a8fba>  
 <caption>SUBFORM - Common Tasks</caption>
    <tr>
    <th>Job Title</th>
    <th>Due Date</th>
    <th>Start Date</th>
    <th>Cost</th>
    <th>Priority</th>
    <th>Percent Complete</th>
    <th>Assigned To</th>
    <th>Description</th>
    </tr>";

       if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
     // output data of each row

     while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

       echo "<tr>";
       echo "<td><a href=  $link  > $row[Title]  </a></td>";
       echo "<td>". $row['DueDate'] . "</td>";
       echo "<td>". $row['StartDate'] . "</td> " ;
       echo "<td>". $row['Cost'] . "</td>";
       echo "<td>". $row['Priority'] . "</td>";
       echo "<td>". $row['PercentComplete'] . "</td> " ;
       echo "<td>". $row ['SELECT LastName, FirstName FROM Employees JOIN CommonTasks WHERE Employees.ID = $_GET[AssignedTo] LIMIT 1'] . "</td>";
       echo "<td>". $row['Description'] . "</td> " ;
       echo "</tr>";
    }
}
echo "</table>";
?>
</body>
```

Comment: By the way, the text value of the employees name should come from the FirstName column and the LastName column.. I was trying to use SELECT FirstName, LastName WHERE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, the results are being produced by this line

```
$result = $dbc->query($sql);
```

The following line will not execute a mysql query.

```
echo "<td>". $row ['SELECT LastName, FirstName FROM Employees JOIN CommonTasks WHERE Employees.ID = $_GET[AssignedTo] LIMIT 1'] . "</td>";
```

As written, you are trying to find a row value in $result that does not exist. You need to call the second query within the first while loop and pass the value of $_GET[AssignedTo] which is probably $row[AssignedTo]

Something like this

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

   echo "<tr>";
   echo "<td><a href=  $link  > $row[Title]  </a></td>";
   echo "<td>". $row['DueDate'] . "</td>";
   echo "<td>". $row['StartDate'] . "</td> " ;
   echo "<td>". $row['Cost'] . "</td>";
   echo "<td>". $row['Priority'] . "</td>";
   echo "<td>". $row['PercentComplete'] . "</td> " ;

   $emp = "SELECT LastName, FirstName FROM Employees JOIN CommonTasks WHERE Employees.ID = '$row[AssignedTo]' LIMIT 1";
   $result2 = @mysqli_query($dbc, $emp);
   $row2 = $result2->fetch_assoc();


   echo "<td>". $row2 ['Firstname'] . " ". $row2 ['Lastname'] . "</td>";
   echo "<td>". $row['Description'] . "</td> " ;
   echo "</tr>";
}
```

Comment: I tried that, and that produces the same blank in the [AssignedTo] field/column on the page.

Comment: I did try      echo "<td>". print_r($row2 ['Firstname'] . " ". $row2 ['Lastname']) . "</td>"; and it produces a "1" in each row of the [AssignedTo] column.

Comment: OK, So I finally figured it out.

Comment: $emp = "SELECT LastName, FirstName FROM Employees JOIN CommonTasks WHERE Employees.ID = '$row[AssignedTo]'";
   $result2 = @mysqli_query($dbc, $emp);
   $row2 = $result2->fetch_assoc();


   echo "<td>". $row2['LastName']," , ",$row2[FirstName] . "</td>";

Answer (score 0):

So, Here are my revisions to your example:

```html
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

   echo "<tr>";
   echo "<td><a href=  $link  > $row[Title]  </a></td>";
   echo "<td>". $row['DueDate'] . "</td>";
   echo "<td>". $row['StartDate'] . "</td> " ;
   echo "<td>". $row['Cost'] . "</td>";
   echo "<td>". $row['Priority'] . "</td>";
   echo "<td>". $row['PercentComplete'] . "</td> " ;

   $emp = "SELECT LastName, FirstName FROM Employees JOIN CommonTasks WHERE Employees.ID = '$row[AssignedTo]'";
   $result2 = @mysqli_query($dbc, $emp);
   $row2 = $result2->fetch_assoc();


   echo "<td>". $row2['LastName']," , ",$row2[FirstName] . "</td>";
   echo "<td>". $row['Description'] . "</td> " ;
   echo "</tr>";
}
}
echo "</table>";
?>
```

Which produces this: [Results of modified code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ubkZ.png)

Thank you so much for your Help!
Since I am converting an Access Database to mySQL and recreating all of the queries, forms, and reports.... I am sure I will have an overwhelming amount of questions in the near future.

Eric

Comment: no problem, happy to help.  if you feel my answer is correct please mark it so.